# PHP to do what ImageMagick does

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to find some PHP code to essentially do what the ImageMagick command `">compare -metric AE -fuzz 10% image1.png image2.png output.png"` does.  I have found the http://www.phpied.com/image-diff/ code and it does well, but I really need the `-fuzz` capabilities to filter out the insignificant differences and it would be nice to have the `-metric` flag functionality to spit out the difference count, but I would think that is pretty easy to add.

Reason for this is that I can't install ImageMagick on my web server so I need standalone code or libraries.

Any suggestions on code or places to look?

Thanks

Comment: So you can or cannot install ImageMagick binaries? If they're available, making a system call to ImageMagick executables is the easiest...

Comment: ImageMagick is not installed on my webserver and I do not have rights to install it.  I would do it that way if I could but no go.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/imagick) functions of PHP?

Comment: Not a thing, I just dont have ImageMagick at my disposal.

Comment: If it's because you're with a shared host and don't have shell access, I'd be looking for an alternative host if they're not providing default access to such an integral library and especially if they are unwilling to install it upon request. Re-writing any of ImageMagick's functions in PHP  is going to take a **lot** more time/effort than moving to (or offloading this task) to another server with `imagick` or `imagemagick`.